# Javascript. Притормаживания при нескольких нажатиях на телефон

Tags: javascript, mobile

Пытаюсь сделать мобильную игрульку на телефоне (js,html). Для управления используется поле, которое работает как джойстик. Относительно центра поля пальцем указывается направление движения юнита по полю.

```
var touch = document.getElementById("touch");
touch.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    glb.PP = true;  
    glb.PX = e.touches[0].pageX; 
    glb.PY = e.touches[0].pageY;    
}, false);
touch.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) { glb.PP = false; }, false);
touch.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    glb.PX = e.touches[0].pageX; 
    glb.PY = e.touches[0].pageY;    
}, false);
```

Это работает нормально. Теперь добавляю кнопку для стрельбы в другую часть экрана.

```
var knpFire = document.getElementById("knpFire");
knpFire.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) { glb.Fire = true; }, false);
knpFire.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) { glb.Fire = false; }, false);
```

Это тоже работает. По отдельности работает идеально. Но если пытаться стрелять при ходьбе (т.е. при зажатом #touch, тапать по #knpFire), то при каждом тапе по экрану появляются залипания процесса игры. И дело не в увеличении объектов (за счет прибавления пуль), или в чем-то еще, а именно при попытке телефона обработать несколько нажатий.

Пытался объединять объекты для нажатий в одно большое поле и разделять нажатия чисто по координатам. Та же проблема остается.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это исправить, обойти или вообще заменить?

Comment: Элементы управления могут принимать фокус? Вывод через отрисовку в canvas, или созданием элементов? На чем реализован основной цикл, `setInterval` или `requestAnimationFrame`?

Comment: На счет фокуса не понял. Там див с кружком в бекграунде (чтобы видно было куда тыкать). 
Вывод был через простой html/css/js, но сейчас вот как раз переделываю на canvas, может как-то поможет, хоть немного. Кроме этого и просто появилась необходимость в канвасе, когда карту для игры увеличил раз в 5, все и без кликов затупило страшно)) Цикл, когда писал сообщение был на setInterval, позже нагуглил, что есть requestAnimationFrame, поменял на него и немного пошустрее стало, но все равно явно проблема с тормозами при тапах не решилась.

Comment: Вывод через canvas с циклом на rAF должен решить проблему. Если не решит - то это уже будет странно, и тогда для ответа потребуется [mcve].